# JavaFX : Scrollbar not visible on resize

Tags: java, javafx

I have the below fxml file but for some reason `Scrollbar` is not visible on resizing the window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="mdg1ContentPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="1000.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefViewportHeight="700.0" prefViewportWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <GridPane>
               <children>
                  <GridPane hgap="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" vgap="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="General Settings">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 15;" text="Copy" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets top="1.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Label text="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Label text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
                           <tooltip>
                              <Tooltip text="*Depends on 'Source Type' selection" />
                           </tooltip>
                        </Label>
                        <Label text="5" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                        <Label text="6" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="30.0" text="..." GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="30.0" text="..." GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="30.0" text="..." GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                        <Separator prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <HBox spacing="5.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                           <children>
                              <TextField prefHeight="30.0" promptText="Folder or zip file..." GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" text="zzz" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="3" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <TextField prefHeight="30.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                        <TextField prefHeight="30.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                        <ComboBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="250.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <ComboBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="250.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                        <Label text="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label fx:id="txtFlcFileValue" text="&gt;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="txtLogFolder" text="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                     </children>
                     <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" />
                     </columnConstraints>
                     <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="5.0" minHeight="5.0" prefHeight="5.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
                        <RowConstraints prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
                        <RowConstraints prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
                        <RowConstraints prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
                        <RowConstraints prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
                        <RowConstraints prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
                     </rowConstraints>
                  </GridPane>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.23" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <items>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <TableView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <columns>
                                    <TableColumn prefWidth="70.0" text="1" />
                                    <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="2" />
                                 </columns>
                              </TableView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                        <AnchorPane>
                           <children>
                              <TableView editable="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <columns>
                                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="1" />
                                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="2" />
                                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="3" />
                                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="4" />
                                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="5" />
                                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="6" />
                                    <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="500.0" text="7" />
                                 </columns>
                              </TableView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </items>
                  </SplitPane>
               </children>
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </rowConstraints>
            </GridPane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I have tried changing `fitToWidth` and `fitToHeight` of `ScrollPane` to false. Though ScrollBar appears the size of the content is not occupying full space of parent.

How can i resolve this ? What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Don’t use an AnchorPane.  It’s essentially the equivalent of an absolute layout.  Make your ScrollPane the center child of a BorderPane (or the sole child of a StackPane) instead.